# In what situation should the client choose the unique resource ID for REST URIs and in which should the server specify it?

Tags: api, http, rest, uri

It looks like there are two ways I can make my REST API. I can have users created with a POST without specifying the URI and it will create the user and return the URI OR I can have the create the users with a PUT and specify the URI *themselves*.

When should one be used over the other? The key difference here is that in one method MY system is deciding what the unique ID and thus URI for the resource should be, in the other situation THEY are specifying what it should be when I create.

Answer (score 2):

It basically comes down to whether you are willing to cede the control of resource naming to the client.

The biggest issue simply being dealing with conflicts (If I PUT /photo.png and you PUT /photo.png, is that OK?).

Answer those questions, and you're on your way.

Comment: Not true.  Having the client construct the URI itself breaks one of the principles of RESTful style.

Comment: Yea, no. "The naming authority that assigned the resource identifier, making it possible to reference the resource, is responsible for maintaining the semantic validity of the mapping over time". There's nothing that says the client can not be that naming authority and responsible for the maintenance of the namespace and what the resource mean in that namespace. Also, "...REST relies instead on the author choosing a resource identifier that best fits the nature of the concept being identified". That "author" can be the system, or the client, as defined by the application and its semantics.

Comment: @tomc  The client is allowed to construct URIs based rules defined in the media type. Fielding says it in this article http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven  "allow servers to instruct clients on how to construct appropriate URIs"

Answer (score 0):

When your user is specifying the resource ID, they can PUT to the URI; the ID that they are performing the PUT to is the specification of the resource ID.

When you are specifying the resource ID, they can POST to the URI of the parent / group; your system will assign a URI to the resource, and return that to the client so they can reference their created resource.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question hinges on two more specific questions:

- Do clients know the location of the resource to be created?  (This might be the case if, for instance, users are accessed via the *name* of the user rather than a server-assigned ID.)
- Do clients have a full representation of the resource to be created?  (This might *not* be the case if some portion of your resource is computed by the server.)

If the answer to both of those questions is 'yes', then a PUT is probably appropriate.  If you answered 'no' to either, then you ought to stick with a POST.

Comment: You can still PUT a representation and have the server compute parts of it.

Comment: @Darrel Miller: it's certainly true that you can!  However, I would interpret the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) as prescribing that PUTs be done with a full resource, rather than a partial resource that is modified behind the scenes.  (Eg. "requests that the enclosed entity be stored", or "identifies the entity enclosed with the request".)

Comment: But nothing in HTTP says anything about the representation of the resource, so that certainly leaves it up to the application exactly what the appropriate representations are as well as what the definitions of "complete" and "partial".

Comment: The explanation of PUT has been greatly expanded in Httpbis to try and clarify this issue and others. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-14#page-18

Answer (score 0):

> I can have users created with a POST
>   without specifying the URI and it will
>   create the user and return the URI OR
>   I can have the create the users with a
>   PUT **and specify the URI themselves**.
>
> When should one be used over the
>   other?

Use the first.

In RESTful HTTP the client should **never** construct URIs.  The service should be *well-connected*, which means that the client should only ever follow URIs given by the server and make requests to those URIs.

It creates better separation between the client and server, and makes it easier to make changes to the service without breaking existing clients.

(And yes, *lots* of existing APIs get this wrong)

There's a really good post by Fielding related to this topic here:

http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: [URI templates](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#Template_grammar) can keep an API hypertext-driven while still allowing clients to customize requests.

Comment: In my _personal_ opnion POST/redirect is such a simple & standardized idiom, that I'd argue it ought to be the default unless you've got a good reason to choose otherwise.  Although that's certainly not canon.

Comment: URI templates are not the only way a server can instruct clients on how to construct URIs, but they are definitely one of the better ways.  The key is to ensure that the media type or link relation specification documents the customization mechanism.